# Using Mod_Rewrite to redirect from one URL to another

Tags: .htaccess

I want to route anyone trying access:

`www.domain.com/shop_en/proddetail.php?prod=333`

To the following URL:

`www.domain.com/shop/product/333`

how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?shop/product/([^/d]+)/?$ shop_en/proddetail.php?prod=$1 [L,QSA]
```